# How to use PHP to create session ID so it appears as Primary Key in SQL database

Tags: php, sql

I am an a near absolute beginner in PHP and in the use of SQL database, so I would appreciate your help. I wish to write a PHP code that will allow me to capture or "track" the session ID of people who are filling in a form that I have created using PHP. I understand that to create a session VARIABLE, you write the following code:

```
            <html>
               <body>

                  <?php
                      //retrieve session data
                           echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['views'];
             ?>

            </body>
       </html>
```

But it's NOT a session variable that I want. It's a session ID that I need, such as this:

```
         192.178.201.233 Tue Aug 21 15:00:22 UTC+0500 2014
```

Could anyone please tell me how I can create a session ID using a PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

To answer:

> Could anyone please tell me how I can create a session ID using a PHP
>   code?

Use [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) to get the current session's ID which you can use for the lookup in your database.

You say you need this `192.178.201.233 Tue Aug 21 15:00:22 UTC+0500 2014` but that is simply an IP address and a timestamp, you could store that in the database via the session id? Your question is quite confusing.

Comment: I was told that that was a session ID and I simply took their word for it. Like I said, I'm a near absolute beginner. Thanks for pointing out the website!

Answer (score 0):

The function [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) will return the current session ID if a session exists, or an empty string if not.  [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) may be used to start a session with the current request.